# A general question on nonnegative integer sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, set-theory, sequences-and-series

Let $A=\{x\ |\ x\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0},\ x\ $ with some conditions$\ \}$.
Let $B=\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}-A$.
Define $\ 2A= \{a+b : a \in A,\ b \in A\}$.
Define $\ 2B=\{a+b : a \in B,\ b \in B\}$.
Then the set $\ \{n,\ n+1k ,\ n+2k, \ ...\}\ \subseteq\ 2A\ $or $\ 2B$ for some positive  integers $n,k$?

Comment: No: $A=\{ 2n: n\ge 0 \}$

Comment: @ChristianRemling  If $\ A=\{2n:n≥0\}\ $,then $B=\{1,3,5,...\},2B =  \mathbb Z_{\ge 2}$ for n=2?

Comment: Certainly not, as the sum of two odd numbers is even.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks,I revised the question

Comment: Define $A$ to contain the interval $[2^{2^n},2^{2^{n+1}}]$ if and only if $n$ is odd and positive.  We have recently suggested that you stop asking basic questions here, but you've just asked another one.

Comment: @S.Carnahan Thanks,A or B should be consecutive set.

Comment: What is a "consecutive set"?

Comment: @S.Carnahan Consecutive set looks like this:$\ \{x\ |\ x\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0},\ x=\ $some forms$\ \}$.

Comment: What is a "form"?  These words are not standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As suggested by S. Carnahan (with the exact numbers tweaked),
$$
A = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty [3^{2k},3^{2k+1}) \quad\text{and}\quad B = \Bbb N\setminus A = \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty [3^{2k+1},3^{2k+2}).
$$
Then
$$
2A \subset \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty [3^{2k},2\cdot3^{2k+1}) \quad\text{and}\quad 2B \subset \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty [3^{2k+1},2\cdot3^{2k+2}),
$$
and hence both $2A$ and $2B$ have arbitrarily large gaps; this prohibits either set from containing an infinite arithmetic progression.

Comment: Thanks,How about $A=\{x\ |\ x\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0},\ x=\ $some forms$\ \}$?

Comment: As I read this, I get that one picks c_j and d_j and then puts into A and B integers to ensure that c_j ends up in 2A and d_j ends up in 2B.  However, it is also needed for the conclusion that (something like) c_j does not end up in 2B and d_j does not end up in 2A.  How do we get this guarantee?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: hmm, I think you're exactly right. Thanks for pointing out the error. S. Carnahan's comment on the OP seems more correct. (At least this gave me the opportunity to learn that one can't delete an accepted answer....)

Comment: At least you can edit it, give Scott's answer with attribution, and assuage your guilt by making the answer CW.

Comment: Well, I didn't feel all that guilty :) but I still followed your good suggestion.